# Java REST service PUT parameters

Tags: java, rest, jersey

This is how my Jersey Rest web service's a few methods looks likes, I have some methods to update the user settings like:

```
@PUT
@Path("/langauge")
@Consumes("text/plain")
public void updateLanguage(String lang) {

    ***check validity of the lang by string comparisons**
     and update database with the new language*
}

@PUT
@Path("/threshold")
@Consumes("text/plain")
public void updateThreshold(Long threshold) {

   *//check value and update in server*
}
```

Now I have a few questions here;

1- Instead of different resource paths for different update options, is it better to create one resource and update with query parameters? This looks more Restish but I'm not sure I really should change it to something like, because in future if there are more parameters to be updated than it will be very cluttered, while having independent paths looks more clear?

```
@PUT
@Path("/settings/{lang}/{threshold}")
@Consumes("text/plain")
public void updateSettings(@PathParam("threshold") String thre,
        @PathParam("lang") String lang,
        @DefaultValue("") @QueryParam) {


}
```

2- Another question is while updating the language now I accept a language as a string then check if thats valid or not in server, So when client uses this method they don't know what exactly should they send as valid parameters. Is there a way to make this more user friendly, putting some comments on WADL file is an option, but is there another more REST way of doing this?

Comment: I think for User Settings(PUT) use case you should make use of Request Body than query or path parameters. Reason : If settings increase in future you wont have to worry about url length and size and your methods parameters cluttering will also be taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the entire scope of your application, I'd say, you could consider the settings a resource and the particular options as the member of the collection of settings. This would allow to add new settings (downside is, that a client that wants to update multiple would need to know and call all of them):

```
/settings/language
/settings/threshold
...
# later
/settings/timeout
/settings/temperature
```

You could implement the `GET` method on each of the options to display information to the interested client (either as HTML or text or some other format).

Another way would be to collect all settings at one endpoint and to accept a request entity in some format (e.g. JSON) as a representation of all available settings. This approach can be observed in the wild in the elasticsearch APIs (e.g. here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-update-settings.html).

Comment: tnx so parameter approach is not any better than having different paths?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, threshold and language are independent, so your path approach might not be the best approach. Considering option names as ids of the resource *settings* could be interpreted as RESTful with a bit of good will, but I would guess the compound approach might be the more common one.

Comment: those are all in "usersettings" table in DB. You mean /settings/{lang}/{threshold} is better?

Comment: I dont want to make bulk update, which requires more logic on both client server side

Comment: No, by compound I meant: one endpoint and bigger request entity.

Comment: @Spring: it does not need to be a bulk update, the client could only send the options it wants to change. But then again, I don't know your other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Answers :

1) Since they are separate resources, they should have separate service methods. So the earlier approach is great. That makes your code flexible.

2) You can give unique IDs to each of your resources (language in this case) and use it to update the language like:

```
api/language/{languageId}
```

This ID could them be auto-generated through the database or you could define some other mechanism.

Comment: tnx but how does user knows which user id  it should send? still he needs to be informed about valid inputs likewise language string?

Comment: If you are talking from the UI point of view, then you can provide the user a list of the available languages using GET on /languages, then the user will select the language to update. During this update, you can use the ID of the selected language from the earlier response (generally a JSON or XML).